# Dropdownlist not updating onchange when using Dependent Dropdowns

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have three dropdown lists which are dependent on each other. I want to be able to set the third DD to null whenever the first dropdown is chosen but so far my script is not doing anything. It's updating the second DD but not the third.

When all DD's are set and I update the 1st DD, it updates the 2nd but does not set the 3rd to null.

Here is my script:

```
echo CHtml::dropDownList('island_id',$island,$locationsList, 
          array('ajax'=>array('type'=>'POST',
                'url'=>CController::createUrl('supplierHead/getRegions'),
                'update'=>'#region_id',),
                'id'=>'island_id',
                'empty'=>'Choose Island',
                'onchange'=>'$("#province_id").html("<option value=''>Choose Province</option>")'
     )); 
echo " ";
echo CHtml::dropDownList('region_id',$region, $regionsList, 
          array('ajax'=>array('type'=>'POST',
                'url'=>CController::createUrl('supplierHead/getProvinces'),
                'update'=>'#province_id',),
                'id'=>'region_id',
                'empty'=>'Choose Region',
     ));
echo " ";
echo CHtml::dropDownList('province_id',$province,$provincesList, array('empty'=>'Choose Province'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
echo CHtml::dropDownList('island_id',$island,$locationsList, 
          array('ajax'=>array('type'=>'POST',
                'url'=>CController::createUrl('supplierHead/getRegions'),
                'update'=>'#region_id',),
                'id'=>'island_id',
                'empty'=>'Choose Island',
                'onchange'=>'$("#province_id,#region_id").children().html("<option value=''>Choose Province/region</option>")'
     ));
```

Comment: Can you explain to me what the 'onchange' does exactly?

Comment: The onchange event is fired every time you change the selected option in dropdown list. Hence, whenever the option in island_id will change, the values of the other two drop down lists will be set to "Choose Province/Region"

Comment: So if I only want the province_id drop down list to change, I should take out the #region_id inside the 'onchange' ?

Because that's what I did before and it didn't reflect any change at all.

Comment: Yes. Binding a single ID in onchange event shall change the content of only that addressable DOM element. And I hope it's working now, isn't it?

Comment: It ruinds the UI. It only loads the header. I'm assuming there maybe a syntax error?

Comment: Oh yes, it will. Please tell me what framework is it? I mean, if you have JS files included, I can help by providing a function rather. So, are you including any JS (or jquery) files?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48937/discussion-between-marcus-and-user3278616)